# Difference between var a = {arr:[], method:function method(){console.log(this.arr)}} and var a = {arr:[], method:function(){console.log(this.arr)}}

Tags: javascript

```
1. var a = {
             arr:[], 
             method:function method(){
                     console.log(this.arr)} //this is undefined
             }
2. var a = arr:[], 
             method:function(){
                     console.log(this.arr)} //this gives a
             }
```

Can somebody explain me why `this` context gets lost in the first example?

Comment: Nope it isnt. The only difference is that you can call *method* inside the first *method* ...

Comment: There's no contexts in you example at all. Please show a use case which reproduces your issue.

Comment: What makes you think the `this` context gets lost? For more details, google for "JavaScript named function expression".

Comment: @Jonasw In that case the context will be lost, if calling directly `method()` within `a.method`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a named function expression the second is anonymous. The first one will be better for stack trace.